# ios - navigationItem.titleView blinks when updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIView`, holding a `UIButton`, set as my `navigationItem.titleView`. When I update the text for this button, it briefly blinks (disappearing and reappearing with the new text.)

Is there anyway to keep it visible when it's changed? So, if I change 2015-2016 it appears as if only the last digit is updated to 6?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far? As far as I know, setting any value on a `UIView` will cause the `layoutSubviews` method to be called on that view. That will refresh the `UIView` and you normally don't have any control on how that behaves.

Comment: The button that I use in the titleView is set as a property of the current viewController, so I just [_buttonNavTitle setTitle:@"2016" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; and that's when it blinks. Doesn't seem like there's really any way around it... not a big deal, but would be a nice to have.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved my problem and posted the answer if you care to know.

Comment: I don't have a button in the custom view, and the titleView still blinks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem. This has more to do with UIButton than anything in the `navigationBar`'s `titleView`.

If a `UIButton` is set as `[yourButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]`, then it will not blink when it has been updated with `[yourButton setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: THANK YOU so much. This problem has been plaguing me for many months, and is very unsightly. Changing my button to UIButtonTypeCustom fixed the problem straight away!

Comment: As I don't have a button, I can't use this solution.